# Modify HttpClient to include handler after creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have an ASP.net core app, and I am not so familiar with ASP.net programming and have come across a problem.

I am developing a library which will execute http requests against an IoT device.  Each instance of the IoT device stores details such as;

- IpAddress
- Username (optional)
- Password (optional)

So typically the "main" calling application (the ASP.net core app) using the library will create multiple instances, each representing a unique device.  The instance will typically have a life span of less than 1 minute.

I would like to inject httpclient into the library from the calling application.  This has two advantages that I see:
Logs generated by the injected httpclient will be shown in the main application

Httpclients will be managed in just a single location by the main application.  Which I understand is best practice, and that you shouldn't create a httpclient for each request (or group of requests).

The issue I have however, is that some instances of the IoT devices require authentication.  This requires that when creating the HttpClient that a HttpClientHandler is created with the credential information.  Like this:

```cs
return new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
    PreAuthenticate = true
};
```

But this can only be done when creating the HttpClient itself, so needs to be done before injection.  But at that time, then I don't know if it is required, and what the credentials would be.

I thought about injecting `IHttpClientFactory` instead, but that only allows me to create HttpClients with the default configuration, so I still can't specify a handler for it.

So I need some method of modifying the injected HttpClient to include the HttpClientHandler after creation.

Or perhaps is is some other method that I can use to get around this issue?

Comment: You must use the [http message handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my own problem.

I spent ages looking at `MessageHandlers`, looking into using `HttpRequestMessage.Options` and even low level options like `SocketsHttpHandler`.  But the issue with all of these options remained that at program startup time I would need to know the Authorisation information, but I only know this at much later when the application is running (and it can change on the fly as well, which I manage by refreshing the config every x minutes).

It might have taken me a while, but in the end it is very simple, and I don't know why I didn't recognise it before.

Previously, when calling the HttpRequest I was using the `GetAsync()` method of HttpClient, like this

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint, cancellationToken);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The `GetAsync()` command is part of the problem, once I (eventually) found out that the `SendAync()` command was available with more options, then this became the solution.

So now I create my own `HttpRequestMessage` in which I can specify any headers I might require for authentication purposes.

So now I have

```
//Create my get request
HttpRequestMessage request = new()
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = uri
};

//If authentication is required
if (MyConnectionOptions != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyConnectionOptions.Username))
{
    string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MyConnectionOptions.Username + ":" + MyConnectionOptions.Password));
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", svcCredentials);
}

//Execute request with manually created RequestMessage
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
```

And in the main calling application, I can continue to inject HttpClient